# Como acessar uma lista de outra classe em C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8-1, lista

Estou tentando acessar a lista ListaDeContatos da classe Contato na classe ListaContatos para exibir. O problema é que embora a lista seja preenchida em Contato, em ListaContatos ela aparece vazia.

```
    public class Contato
        {
            string Nome { get; set; }
            string Numero {get; set; }

            public List<Contato> ListaDeContatos = new List<Contato>();
            public async void Buscar()
            {
                 ContactStore contactStore;
                 contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
                 var contatos = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

                 foreach (var item in contatos)
                 {
                      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.FirstName))
                      {                                      
                           ListaDeContatos.Add(new Contato() { Nome = item.FirstName.ToString() + " " + item.LastName.ToString(), Numero = "12345678" });
                 }
            }
    }

        public sealed partial class ListaContatos : Page
    {       
        public ListaContatos()
        {
...         
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            Contato contato = new Contato();
            contato.Buscar();
            listView.ItemsSource = contato.ListaDeContatos;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu método Buscar() não tem return e você esta utilizando uma variável estática dentro do método Buscar(), portanto você não vai conseguir preencher seu objeto ListaDeContatos.

Crie o método buscar e retorne a lista preenchida:

```
 public async ListaDeContatos Buscar()
 {
   return ListaDeContatos;
 }
```